# Find inflection points of $e^{\cos x}$

Tags: calculus

I got a function

> $$ f(x) = e^{\cos x}$$

I would like to find inflection points of the function above within range $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$

Find first derivative
$$f'(x) = e^{\cos x}(-\sin x)$$
Find second derivative 
$$f''(x) = e^{\cos x}(-\sin x)(-\sin x) + e^{\cos x}(-\cos x) =  e^{\cos x }\sin^2 x + e^{\cos x}(-\cos x) = e^{\cos x } (\sin^2 x -\cos x )$$

Let $f(x) = 0$

$$e^{\cos x } (\sin^2 x -\cos x ) = 0 \implies $$
Since $e^{\cos x } ≠ 0$ for any $x$, we only consider $(\sin^2 x -\cos x )$
$$(\sin^2 x -\cos x ) = 0 \implies $$
$$\sin^2 x = \cos x  \implies $$
$$\sqrt{1 - cos^2 x} = \cos x  \implies $$
$$1 - cos^2 x = \cos^2 x  \implies $$
$$1  = 2\cos^2 x  \implies $$
$$0.5  = \cos^2 x  \implies $$
$$\cos^2 x = 0.5 $$
$$\cos x = ± \sqrt{0.5} $$

$\arccos(\sqrt{0.5}) \approx 0.78, -0.78$

$\arccos(-\sqrt{0.5}) \approx 2.37 \text{ and } 2\pi - 2.37$

But when I subsitute values above into $(\sin^2 x -\cos x )$, I get:

$$\sin^2(0.78) - \cos(0.78) \approx 0.71$$
$$\sin^2(-0.78) - \cos(-0.78) \approx 0.71$$
$$\sin^2(2.37)  - \cos(2.37) \approx -0.71$$
$$\sin^2(2\pi - 2.37) - \cos(2\pi - 2.37) \approx -0.71$$

Yet the answer I expected to see was $0$. Where have I made the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in your steps.

\begin{eqnarray}
\sin^2x - \cos x &=& 0\\
1-\cos^2 x -\cos x &=& 0\\
\cos^2x +\cos x -1 &=&0
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You have to solve$$\sin^2(x)=\cos(x)$$ this is $$1-\cos^2(x)=\cos(x)$$ now solve a quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:  There is indeed a local maximum at $x=0$:

[image]

$$f^\prime (x) = \sin (x) \left(-e^{\cos (x)}\right) = 0$$

implies $\sin x = 0$ (or $x=0$) is a solution too.